# WPF DependencyProperty in ContentControl does not bind TwoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have custom `ContentControl`

```
public class FilteringColumnHeader : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextFieldProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextField", typeof(string), typeof(FilteringColumnHeader), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string TextField
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextFieldProperty);
        }
        set { SetValue(TextFieldProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

With this template style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:FilteringColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:FilteringColumnHeader}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding TextField}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is how I use it in `DataGrid` in XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" MinWidth="50">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <c:FilteringColumnHeader Content="{Binding }" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=NameColumn}" TextField="{Binding DataContext.NameFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:GeneratorsListView}}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

And GeneratorsListView

```
private string nameFilter = "rec";
public string NameFilter
{
    get { return nameFilter; }
    set
    {
        nameFilter = value;
    }
}
```

My problem is, the `Text` binding works only OneWay. When I run the code TextBox will be filled with "rec" and when I change the `NameFilter`, the TextBox also changes. But when I type something in that box, nothing happens (setter of `NameFilter` is not being invoked at all). As you can see I've tried to set mode to `TwoWay` everywhere I could, still nothing. When I pleace regular `TextBox` inside `DataTemplate` and set the exact same Text binding, it is working.

Comment: TemplateBinding  is never twoway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{TemplateBinding}` is an optimized version of a binding with a mode of `OneWay` so if you want the property to get updated you should use an ordinary binding with the `RelativeSource` set to `TemplatedParent`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:FilteringColumnHeader}">
    <DockPanel>
        <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextField, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```